# Getting files list from android/emulated/0/Download

Tags: android

Hello I'm writing application and one of it function is reading downloaded data, I want to get all files that android/emulated/0/Download contains. I know that it is a internal storage, I have in Manifest file only permission for external storage, I don't know how to add permission for reading data from this directory.

```
 ArrayList<String> files = findURs(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), new ArrayList<String>());
```

this code was wrote by another user but I only eddited it

```
public ArrayList<String> findURs(File dir, ArrayList<String> matchingURFileNames) {
    String safPattern = ".ur";

    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                findURs(listFile[i], matchingURFileNames);
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(safPattern)) {
                    matchingURFileNames.add(dir.toString() + File.separator + listFile[i].getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return matchingURFileNames;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do a runtime permision check like this,

```
private int REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

 private void checkPermissions() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE);


    } else {

       ArrayList<String> files = findURs(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), new ArrayList<String>());

    }



}
```

Handle your permission results in,

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

           ArrayList<String> files = findURs(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), new ArrayList<String>());

            }
        }
    }
```

Also add in manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```