# How to get all files list under specific path

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to add every file inside specific folder to listview using kotlin but the code only returns the path/file which is defined as path in code:

```
val letovi: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    File("/storage/emulated/0/").walkBottomUp().forEach {
      letovi.add(it.toString())
    }
      val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,letovi)
      flightList.adapter = arrayAdapter
}
```

The xml part:

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/flightList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

For example, this code above puts only one line to listview `/storage/emulated/0/`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting files list from android/emulated/0/Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49157833/getting-files-list-from-android-emulated-0-download)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is your code in Kotlin to get files list under specific path**

```
val files = File("your_path").listFiles()
val fileNames = arrayOfNulls<String>(files.size)
files?.mapIndexed { index, item ->
    fileNames[index] = item?.name
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is **true**. You need to request **permission** for read external storage (runtime).

```
 fun isReadStoragePermissionGranted(): Boolean {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            true
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
            false
        }
    } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        true
    }
}

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if(requestCode == 1){
            if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                // some code
            }
            else{
                // some code
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This bit is very important, especially if you're trying to list all the directories or files under a directory for deletion or manipulation. In my case in order to be able to delete the files I changed it to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It should work. My bet is that you do not have permissions set up accordingly. Make sure you add `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your manifest or force the user to accept the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission via permission dialog.

Comment: I have already did that long before, i have permissions for internet, reading and writing external storage.

Comment: Hm, let me test your code and I will improve my answer if I find the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Kotlin, but in Java I have done something like this, which may helps:

```
File[] existingFiles = new File(path).listFiles();
for (File F : existingFiles) {
  // do something with File, e.g. "F.getName()"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

```
 if (!file!!.exists()) {
            file!!.mkdir()
        }
```